# How to fix the error of NERDTree when I press m to show the menu

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When I press "m" to show the menu of NERDTree, an error occured and show as below

```
NERDTree Menu. Use j/k/enter and the shortcuts indicated
==========================================================
Error detected while processing function <SNR>11_showMenu..30..31:
line    4:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: menuItems)-1)
E116: Invalid arguments for function len(self.menuItems)-1)
E116: Invalid arguments for function range(0, len(self.menuItems)-1)
E15: Invalid expression: range(0, len(self.menuItems)-1)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How to fix it???

Comment: It looks like NERDTree is not correctly installed. Where and how did you install it?

Comment: I install it again, now it works well THANKS~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot Vim plugin problems, first check whether it is a problem on your side:

- Verify that the problem is not caused by your setup, by testing the plugin in isolation: Backup your `.vimrc` and `~/.vim` / `vimfiles` directory, clean it, keep / reinstall just the plugin itself.
- Maybe there's a newer version available by now. Check http://www.vim.org or the site from where you got the plugin.
- Try reinstalling the plugin or installing on a different system.

If the problem persists, contact the plugin author. He's best suited to help you, and most interested in bugs and fixes. His email is usually found in the accompanying documentation or header of the plugin.

Some older plugins are not maintained any more by the original author. An Internet search might bring up forks or alternative implementations. If there is none, the plugin's license (usually the Vim license or a common open source one like GPL or MIT) allows you to take over maintenance and start publishing your own versions. The community is grateful for this!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by install the package through [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) instead of putting it directly in the plugins folder.